# save game data in Net Logo Web

Tags: netlogo

is there any way to save game data in NetLogo Web?
In my NetLogo model all important data is written in the output and the content of the output is exported automatically at the end of each game. Unfortunately I read on the NetLogo Web homepage that the export-output primitive is currently not implemented. Is there any other way to save game data?
Lo